# Devexpress checkbox column in a gridcontrol c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, devexpress

I have a datagrid  from devexpress in a winform application.I populated the datagrid from code (datasource=my datatable with 2 strings columns and one of type int (receive 0 and 1 values-should be checkbox on form).

I added a datagrid and from designer I added 3 columns.The last one of type checkbox.I set

```
UnboundType=Integer,
UnboundExpression=my column name from datatable :
DisplayFormat = Numeric,
columnedit = checkbox,
Displaycheckedvalue = 1,
displayuncheckedvalue = 0.
```

When I run the application always my checkboxes are blue.If i press one checkbox appear a check but when i go to the next row the previous value is again blue.What should i do so why the application keep  the checks?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the column to be unbound, it is in your datasource after all.

What you want to do is just to set Displaycheckedvalue and displayuncheckedvalue as you have done, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class which got a property for each column of your table. The int value would be a bool and so you can use List as datasource. The Grid will automaticly add checkboxes for the bool value.
If you want to use DataTable see Stig's post but in my opinion it is more beautiful to use classes and List.